# describe a vector with a single unique number

Tags: vectors, hash-function

Is there a way to uniquely describe a vector with a single ( = easy to store) value?
e.g. have a function $H(\vec{v}): \mathbb{R}^{130} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

I have a lot of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{130}$ like
$$
    \vec{v} = [0, 0, 0.02408936187094653, 0, 0, 0, -0.0009220896553828633, 0, 0.013715033276784966, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.086923156150
    166640478, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.004169024626740706, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.06103892811472592, -0.001827088692541601, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.021119819421521576, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.028956996972808808, 0.01855961039762378, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0030550036310233665, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.04934179336434643, 0, 0, 0, 0]
$$
where most dimensions are $0$.

Is there a good solution to map the vector to a single number (in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{N}$) where every vector is described in a unique way (and same vectors has same results)? I considered using (cryptographic) hash functions like md5, fnv1a, ... but is this a proper solution for vectors in $\mathbb{R}$?

It is not needed to create a isomorphism between $\vec{v}$ and $H(\vec{v})$, this could be done via lookup table. But $x_1 = x_2 \to H(x_1) = H(x_2) \wedge x_1 \neq x_2 \to H(x_1) \neq H(x_2)$

Comment: most likely not in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: if i would use a hash function like FNV1a the result would be in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Actually you may be right, but from a theoretical point of view you wont be able to store  numbers from $\mathbb{R}$ (or higher dimensions) into $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: oh, yes that is of course correct

Comment: @T_O But these aren't really reals, these are floating point values, of which there are only countably many.

Comment: @reox Do you have to be able to reconstruct the vector from the stored value?

Comment: @fgp I'm aware of that, see my 2nd comment

Comment: @fgp no this is not needed. a lookup table would be fine

Comment: Floating point is a rational number anyway, so theoretically, you are mapping $\mathbb{Q}^n$ to $\mathbb{N}$ which is fine. Hashing seems a very good idea. Most programming languages come with a hash map already.